# How to delete certain string of characters in Excel

Tags: excel, character, excel-2010, cell

In Column A I have a load of location that look like this:

```
/UNITED STATES/CALIFORNIA/SAN FRANCISCO/TEST SITE/

/UNITED STATES/ILLINOIS/CHICAGO/PARTS DEPOT/
```

I would like to be able to split this out to 4 different Columns
That looks like this:

```
Column B  - UNITED STATES

Column C  - CALIFORNIA

Column D  - SAN FRANCISCO

Column E  - TEST SITE
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the column, click Data > Text to Columns > Delimited > Next > tick Other and enter a `/` character in the box > click Finish

[image]